# I can't seem to get the glyph to center align on the page

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true" style="align:center"></span>
```

I can see the icon but it is off to the left. I have tried text-align and aligh="center" but nothing seems to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center Glyphicons horizontally using Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229249/how-do-i-center-glyphicons-horizontally-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the span with a container and set it's text-align to center.

```css
.parent-container { text-align:center; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="parent-container">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG thanks so much. I even tried to put it in a <div style=" text-align:center"> and nothing at least I was on the right track thanks again

Comment: That would do the trick, as well. Be sure to mark this as the accepted answer if it solves your question. Thanks!

Comment: see my comment on the question: this is a duplicate... as explained in [my answer on the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23229399/2037924), yours didn't work because you were using `span`, which is an inline element, so you'd either add `display:block` or use a block-level element, like a `div`, as @Daerik did in his example... again, all explained nicely in [my answer given to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23229399/2037924)...